# I want to keep TitleBar visible and stick at top instead of underneath a collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a AppBarLayout with CollapsingToolbar layout and ImageView in it. TitleBar appears when I ScrollUp. But I want to stick it at top and always visible. I have already tried by changing

```
app:layout_collapseMode attribute.
```

Also tried

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlways"
```

But didn't worked either. I have a code as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="25dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="60dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/images"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/window_background"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/viewDetail"
                    android:text="View Detail"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:gravity="bottom|right|end"
                    android:onClick="onClick"/>
               </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution to this. I also add ImageView in `ScrollBarLayout`. Below code worked fine for me !

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/window_background"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/images"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:id="@+id/viewDetail"
                        android:text="View Detail"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:gravity="bottom|right|end"
                        android:onClick="onClick"/>
                   </LinearLayout>
     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```